# Is onpropertychange equivalent to oninput?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, dom-events

Is it reasonably fine to bind an event handler to an element both on the 'input' and 'propertychange' events to target support for IE8 and other browsers?

```
$('.element').on('input propertychange', function(){...});
```

Or are there pitfalls to doing this?

## Edit

Is there a jQuery plugin I can use to support old version of IE?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly the same. It'll fire when there are JavaScript changes, and not just user  changes.

This means that a major pitfall is that you can have infinite recursion if the handler provided makes a JavaScript change to the same `input`, or if there's any sort of circular reference, where `inputA` changes `inputB`, which changes `inputA`.

I was actually working on this earlier today, hoping to find any small differences in the `event` object that would let me differentiate between user originating changes, and JavaScript changes, but I could find none.

## Edit

See [this blog post](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) for a possible jQuery plugin.